# How to do rounded tapers in sketchup

Tags: sketchup

how to do rounded tapers like this on sketchup 2018? What I did was, drawing the shape on both surfaces and tried deleting the surfaces. But it didn't create a new surface on taper. As you can see it has a hole, that you can see inside of that column, I want to fill it with a surface, so it can't be see through.

http://i68.tinypic.com/kbsu1s.jpg [-- the sample pic](http://i68.tinypic.com/kbsu1s.jpg)

Comment: This site is a programmer site, you are more likely to get answers to usage of SketchUp at the SketchUp forums: https://forums.sketchup.com/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is brute force.  Turn on hidden geometry (`View -> Hidden Geometry`) and connect the opposing points to create faces.

Alternatively if you have a shape that matches the cutout, you can use intersection to create the fill faces.  If you are new to SketchUp, I recommend learning about intersection (a simple google search of 'SketchUp intersection' will give you a great starting point).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by doing the following:

[1. Create object you wish to taper and draw the taper shape separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWEUN.png)

[2. Use the Follow Me tool to turn taper into a solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGZwN.png)

[3. Make it a component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zpia.png)

[5. Intersect its faces with model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxjIc.png)

[6. Explode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY35j.png)

[7. Erase unnecessary geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXtvz.png)

[8. Ctrl+Eraser to soften remaining geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVQpg.png)

And you end up with this:

[final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg1Cj.png)

Comment: It would be better if you include the images in the answer instead of providing a link.

Comment: @gaganso I'm a new user and don't yet have enough reputation points(?) to post images.